# C++ desktop GUI testing on Travis CI

Tags: c++, user-interface, travis-ci, desktop-application, xdotool

I enjoy Travis CI a lot for continuous integration testing. I test most of my C++ console, desktop (Qt, SFML) and web (using Wt) applications with it. It is great for testing browser-based applications [and has documented this nicely](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/).

One thing I cannot do is test the GUI of a desktop application on Travis CI.

I need basic things like 'get a window with a certain title/name its size', 'click left mouse button in the center' of the window' and 'send a space to the window'.

I can already do this locally, but only locally, with xdotools, LDTP2 and Sikuli. On Travis CI, however, I cannot get those tools to run successfully. I have been trying to write a [tutorial](https://github.com/richelbilderbeek/testing_cpp_gui_applications_tutorial) about it ([these are my scripts](https://github.com/richelbilderbeek/testing_cpp_gui_applications_tutorial/tree/master/scripts)), I have [contacted the folks at Travis](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6006) and even [set a bounty here](https://github.com/richelbilderbeek/testing_cpp_gui_applications_tutorial/issues/3), all without success.

Because this is a complex process (setting up a windows manager on Travis, writing desktop applications to test, writing scripts to test these in bash) I think it is not useful to post those little individuals errors here (most have answers here already).

**My question is**: does anyone have a working example of

- a non-web C++ GUI application
- that has its GUI tested both locally and on Travis
- these tests consist out of sending key presses and mouse clicks

I do not care about the exact tools (xdotools or some other window manager tool, Qt or some other C++ GUI library, bash or any other scripting language). All I want is to have Travis CI check my GUI upon a `git push`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but the syntax of the stuff you have attempted might be the cause of why it has been breaking for you.

In the [upstream issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6006), repeatedly the following is used:

```
var=value; program
```

Could you try and use the following syntax instead:

```
var=value program
```

or

```
export var=value; program
```

Explanation: The `;` is a terminator of the expression, and the variable that has just been set is not available for child PIDs. Either exporting the variable, or using the special syntax (without `;` as a separator) will make the variable just set available for the child PID.

Comment: That is helpful. I will try this out now. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried to use it, but https://travis-ci.org/richelbilderbeek/testing_cpp_gui_applications_tutorial#L948 shows this has not been the problem. Thanks for the help though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have here:

[Nana C++ GUI test in Travis](https://travis-ci.org/cnjinhao/nana/jobs/167669530#L1468)

[Other click](https://travis-ci.org/cnjinhao/nana/jobs/167669530#L1496), in travis:

```
3.04s$ ./clicked
Will wait 2 sec...
waiting 2 sec...
running... 
3 times automatic click. 
Automatically clicking widget :
When the window  fm  is clicked, this function is called. 
Automatically clicking widget :
When the window  fm  is clicked, this function is called. 
Automatically clicking widget :
When the window  fm  is clicked, this function is called. 
Now with then mouse. 
Congratulations, this was not trivial !
Done... 
Now again waiting 1 sec...
Done... Now API::exit all ...
```

programmed [here](https://github.com/qPCR4vir/nana-demo/blob/master/Examples/clicked.cpp#L24).

```
void clicked(const nana::arg_click & eventinfo)
{
     std::cout<<  "When the window  fm  is clicked, this function is called. \n";
}



int main()
{
    using namespace nana;
    form fm;
    fm.events().click(clicked);
    fm.show();
    exec( 2, 1, [&fm]()
        {
            std::cout << "3 times automatic click. \n";
            click(fm);
            click(fm);
            click(fm);

            nana::arg_mouse m;
            m.window_handle=fm;
            m.alt=m.ctrl=m.mid_button=m.shift=false;
            m.left_button=true;
            m.pos.x=m.pos.y=1;
            m.button=::nana::mouse::left_button;

            std::cout << "Now with then mouse. \n";
            //fm.events().mouse_down.emit(m);
            //fm.events().mouse_up.emit(m);

            // char c;
            // std::cin >> c;

            //fm.close();

         });
}
```

This is far from ready, is only my initial idea. My biggest problem is that I have no experience with GUI in linux. I implemented just a few test, a few examples, which for now is enough for us to detect big problems. I test localy in Windows (well, when I have the time...) but no way I personally can test in linux, so, Travis is for me very useful. 
I invented a few functions to write the test inside the GUI library self. Is not (yet) very elegant. I hope I will have the time to make it better. I will love to see your solutions.

Comment: I am happy to hear you to enjoy decent unit testing. Too bad it does not answer my question, e.g. 'get a window with a certain title/name its size'. I too am able to manipulate my windows from within an application. I want to send key presses and mouseclicks from outside of the program.